# Flush trim pattern router bit

Tags: router-bit

I am attempting to replicate router cuts

[image]

I made a template and am having difficulty finding router bit that works.

My template sits on top of the triangle. I tried using a flush cut pattern bit and the depth is set correctly. That works fine but the top bearing seems to hold cut 1/4 inch from where I want the cut.

It does not seem to cut flush with my pattern. The resulting cut is too narrow. What do I need to do?

Comment: Guess picture did not come through. Sorry. Hopefully explanation gives the idea of my problem

Comment: Use a photo hosting site like imgur or postimage; put a link in your edited post; someone will edit your post to include the pic. You might also include a pic of your bit.

Comment: Cut your template hole larger by 1/4".

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I tried another flush cut bit which did ride flush. Now I am not able to get cutter to clear 3/4 inch thick template. Plan to try raising bearing on bit shank by 1/16 inch

Comment: Yeah, the first time I tried template routing, I had the same problem. I made the template too thick. In the future, try making your templates out of hardboard or 1/4" thick MDF. Those are my current go-to materials for shop made router templates.

Comment: Also, there are pattern routing bits and flush trim bits that are longer and could probably do what you want. (The difference is where the bearing is located on the bit; on "pattern bits" the bearing is at the shank, on "flush trim bits" the bearing is past the cutters at the end of the bit). But continually buying bits until you find the right one can certainly become an expensive proposition.

Comment: If you are interested in considering other bits, you might look into the offerings of manufacturers such as Amana, Whiteside, CMT, and Freud. This is not intended to be an endorsement or recommendation, but it can be helpful to look through product offerings to get an idea of what is available on the market. And that's hard to do if you don't know any manufacturers!

Comment: Is the goal to route out the dado's in the triangle ? How about a jig and dado set on the table saw ? Or a jig, instead of a template, to cut dado's with the router ?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you do not, in fact, have a flush cut bit, but rather a hinge mortising bit, such as the [Freud 16-560](https://www.freudtools.com/products/16-560), that is designed for templates that are slightly oversized.
[image]

You can either get a proper flush trim bit, get a different bearing for the bit to make it cut flush, or modify your template to account for the offset.

Comment: Links to pictures are not necessarily persistent so I recommend directly inserting a picture in a post. Thanks

Comment: @ashlar I actually linked to a product page, not an image...I'm not really sure that an image would get the point across.  It's only got a 1/8" offset, so it would be hard to see.  Maybe I should just remove the link altogether and cite the model number instead?

Comment: IMO the link is fine and will hopefully last a long while.  Adding the image is insurance against it disappearing.